# Spark - how to handle with lazy evaluation in case of iterative (or recursive) function calls

Tags: scala, apache-spark, functional-programming, lazy-evaluation

I have a recursive function that needs to compare the results of the current call to the previous call to figure out whether it has reached a convergence. My function does not contain any `action` - it only contains `map`, `flatMap`, and `reduceByKey`.  Since Spark does not evaluate transformations (until an action is called), my next iteration does not get the proper values to compare for convergence.

Here is a skeleton of the function -

```
def func1(sc: SparkContext, nodes:RDD[List[Long]], didConverge: Boolean, changeCount: Int) RDD[(Long] = {

   if (didConverge)
      nodes
   else { 
       val currChangeCount = sc.accumulator(0, "xyz")         
       val newNodes = performSomeOps(nodes, currChangeCount) // does a few map/flatMap/reduceByKey operations
       if (currChangeCount.value == changeCount)  {
          func1(sc, newNodes, true, currChangeCount.value)
       } else {
          func1(sc, newNode, false, currChangeCount.value)
       }
   }
}
```

`performSomeOps` only contains `map`, `flatMap`, and `reduceByKey` transformations. Since it does not have any action, the code in `performSomeOps` does not execute.  So my `currChangeCount` does not get the actual count.  What that implies, the condition to check for the convergence (`currChangeCount.value == changeCount`) is going to be invalid.  One way to overcome is to force an action within each iteration by calling a `count` but that is an unnecessary overhead.

I am wondering what I can do to force an action w/o much overhead or is there another way to address this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe there is a very [important thing](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/programming-guide.html#accumulators) you're missing here:

> For accumulator updates performed inside **actions only**, Spark guarantees that each task’s update to the accumulator will only be applied once, i.e. restarted tasks will not update the value. In transformations, users should be aware of that each task’s update may be applied more than once if tasks or job stages are re-executed.

Because of that accumulators cannot be reliably used for managing control flow and are better suited for job monitoring.

Moreover executing an action is not *an unnecessary overhead*. If you want to know what is the result of the computation you have to perform it. Unless of course the result is trivial. The cheapest action possible is:

```
rdd.foreach { case _ =>  }
```

but it won't address the problem you have here.

In general iterative computations in Spark can be structured as follows:

```scala
def func1(chcekpoinInterval: Int)(sc: SparkContext, nodes:RDD[List[Long]], 
    didConverge: Boolean, changeCount: Int, iteration: Int) RDD[(Long] = {

  if (didConverge) nodes
  else {

    // Compute and cache new nodes
    val newNodes = performSomeOps(nodes, currChangeCount).cache

    // Periodically checkpoint to avoid stack overflow
    if (iteration % checkpointInterval == 0) newNodes.checkpoint

    /* Call a function which computes values
     that determines control flow. This execute an action on newNodes.
    */
    val changeCount = computeChangeCount(newNodes)

    // Unpersist old nodes
    nodes.unpersist

    func1(checkpointInterval)(
      sc, newNodes, currChangeCount.value == changeCount, 
      currChangeCount.value, iteration + 1
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Good points!  I should have noted the restrictions on using accumulator.  Also, I changed my `performSomeOps` to include a reduce (to calculate the changeCount).  It is working fine now.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I see that these `map/flatMap/reduceByKey` transformations are updating an accumulator. Therefore the only way to perform all updates is to execute all these functions and `count` is the easiest way to achieve that and gives the lowest overhead compared to other ways (`cache` + `count`, `first` or `collect`).

Answer (score 0):

Previous answers put me on the right track to solve a similar convergence detection problem.

`foreach` is presented in [the docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.1/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) as:

> `foreach(func)` : Run a function *func* on each element of the dataset. This is usually done for side effects such as updating an Accumulator or interacting with external storage systems.

It seems like **instead of using** `rdd.foreach()` **as a cheap action** to trigger accumulator increments placed in various transformations, it should be used to **do the incrementing** itself.

I'm unable to produce a scala example, but here's a basic java version, if it can still help:

```
// Convergence is reached when two iterations
// return the same number of results
long previousCount = -1;
long currentCount = 0;

while (previousCount != currentCount){
    rdd = doSomethingThatUpdatesRdd(rdd);

    // Count entries in new rdd with foreach + accumulator
    rdd.foreach(tuple -> accumulator.add(1));

    // Update helper values
    previousCount = currentCount;
    currentCount = accumulator.sum();
    accumulator.reset();
}
// Convergence is reached
```